# .htaccess not working at all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I've got a file accessible through my web website by typing http://www.mywebsite.com/myfile and the server run on debian.

I'd like to put an authentication with a .htaccess and .htpasswd when trying to access to previous url.

I'm quite new to .htaccess and I tried to configure it with the doc but it doesn't seems to work since when i try nothing change and when i check the error log I've got :

> [error] [client IP] client denied by server configuration:
>   /home/file1/myfile/www/.htaccess

The content of my .htaccess is :

```
<Directory /home/file1/myfile/www/>
    AuthUserFile /home/file1/myfile/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthName "My authentication"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user

    Otions Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    Redirect permanent /.htaccess http://www.mywebsite.com/myfile
    ServerSignature Off
</Directory>
```

How may I solve this problem please ?

Comment: Do you have your .htaccess in the root of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that deleting et creating again the user is enough to fix the FTP connexion problem.

I've modified my global apache configuration with the following :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.xhtml index.php index.txt

ServerName debian.domain.tld
#ServerName localhost
HostnameLookups Off

ServerAdmin myadressemail

UserDir www
UserDir disable root

<Directory />
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ServerSignature Off
```

An now my .htaccess is :

```
AuthUserFile /home/file1/myfile/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "My authentification"
AuthType Basic
Require user user1
```

But I still have got no authentication asked, what did I do wrong ?

Comment: Just needed to replace Require user user1 by Require valid-user and to change the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `<Directory>` container in an htaccess file. Remove them so you just have:

```
AuthUserFile /home/file1/myfile/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "My authentication"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
deny from all

Redirect permanent /.htaccess http://www.mywebsite.com/myfile
ServerSignature Off
```

(you have `Otions` mispelled)

Also, by looking at your error, it looks as if you were trying to access the htaccess file directly, instead of `myfile`. It's possible there's extra configuration on the server to deny accessing htaccess files (or all files that start with a `.`).

Comment: Actually I do want deny the access to the htaccess. For the moment when I try to access directly to the htaccess, I've got a 403 error but I would like to redirect the user instead.

Unfortunately it stills doesn't work :(

Comment: @bash_profileblank if there is some server configured 403 for htaccess files (for anything that starts with a `.`), the redirect *will never get applied*.

Comment: Ok, so i cannot redirect it. But how come i've got no authentication asked when i access to the url ?

Comment: @bash_profileblank just realized that you have `allow from all`, which needs to be `deny from all`.

Comment: I cannot connect in FTP since i removed the <Directory> container, how do i correct that ?